# the geom_histogram don't provide histogram according to theory

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

[histogram of 120 students](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ql958.jpg)

I used the following r codes to produce the histogram like shown in the image,

```
ggplot(Book2, aes(x=weight, fill=..count..))+
  geom_histogram(bins=11, binwidth = 5)+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(45, 100, by = 5),
                     limits = c(45, 100))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 30, by = 5),
                     limits = c(0, 30))+
  theme_classic()
```

the plot shown by r is given as
[histogram produced in R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsH1x.jpg)
the data is given in pic
[the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CmKk.jpg)
and its frequency distribution is

[its frequency distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJXTi.jpg)

Comment: You can make histograms in a many arbitrary ways. Set the `breaks` manually in `geom_histogram` if you want to exactly reproduce.

Comment: The histogram in the book has a bin width of 5, but is centered around numbers such as `5k + 2` rather than `5k` (as with your R example). Try setting `center = 47` in `geom_histogram` to reproduce the figure in the book with `ggplot2`.

Answer (score 0):

For me it works well and the histogram I get is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lteL5.png). Use the code below for it.

The breaks sometimes can change. Specify it with the specific comand "breaks" inside geom_histogram as you may need.

```
library(ggplot2)
##Creating your data according to the picture
seq<- seq(47,97,5)
repvect<- c(1,4,17,28,25,18,13,6,5,2,1)
weight<-c()

for(i in 1:length(seq)){
  vect<-rep(seq[i], repvect[i])
  weight<-c(vect, weight)
}

Book2<- data.frame(weight) #TRansforming it to a data frame

ggplot(Book2, aes(x=weight, fill=..count..))+
  geom_histogram(bins=11, binwidth = 5)+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(45, 100, by = 5),
                     limits = c(45, 100))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 30, by = 5),
                     limits = c(0, 30))+
  theme_classic()
```

P.D: Remember you need the data in data.frame format to get the histogram.

Cheers!